# Selenium IDE can't find an element

Tags: selenium-ide

I am trying to run a recorded test case in Selenium IDE. The problem is that when I try to execute the whole test case, Selenium stops it not finding an element on page. The problem is that I can execute single steps of the test case. I thought that Selenium tries to find an element before loading a new page, so I used clickAndWait, pause and waitForElementPresent commands - nothing works, Selenium stops the test case.

**debug log**

```
•  [info] Executing: |`clickAndWait` | css=i.fa.fa-arrow-left | | 
•  [debug] Command found, going to execute clickAndWait 
•  [debug] modifyWindow seleniumMarker1429084950752:selenium1429084951105 
•  [debug] _getFrameElement: frameElement=null 
•  [debug] modifySeparateTestWindowToDetectPageLoads: already polling this window: selenium1429084951105 
•  [debug] getCurrentWindow newPageLoaded = false 
•  [error] Element css=i.fa.fa-arrow-left not found 
•  [debug] commandError 
•  [debug] testComplete: failed=true 
•  [info] Test case failed
```

I will be very grateful for any help and suggestions.

Comment: Need more information here. Seeing more of the script would help.  What happens before you execute the clickAndWait on css=i.fa.fa-arrow-left? Have you checked to see if that element exists before the clickAndWait. That seems to be what is implied here.

Comment: Also is there multiple windows involved in this test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain cases where 'ClickAndWait' is not reliable and won't wait for the command to finish before moving to the next command. In such cases, an alternative is to use 'Click' instead and follow it up with a 'waitForPageToLoad'.

Example...

ORIGINAL

```
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>//input[@type='submit']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

NEW

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//input[@type='submit']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForPageToLoad</td>
    <td>10000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

If this doesn't help, please post your source code and I'll see if there's something else I can suggest.

Comment: That's redundant. ClickAndWait does do that. However the AndWait can be triggered on DOM ready which may not have all elements loaded if there is javascript and/or ajax still loading.

Comment: Hi @DMart. I've seen the AndWait fail in some other situations too - particularly in cases where the domain name was set up to forward to an IP rather than bound to an IP. There was no JavaScript or AJAX on the page in this situation and my script wasn't waiting. However it did successfuly Wait when I separated the operation into a Click and a WaitForPageToLoad. In this specific situation, it wasn't redundant.

Comment: It's determined by document['readyState'], specifically !!document['readyState'].
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/6b4e6de722fcccd18619951543143999e9a30657/java/client/src/com/thoughtworks/selenium/webdriven/commands/WaitForPageToLoad.java

More on readystate: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_readystate.asp

Answer (score 0):

I have found much success with this issue (elements not being present yet) by using a combination of waitForElementPresent, verifyElementPresent, and installing the Implicit Wait plugin for the IDE.  (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-implicit-wait/).  I have now almost completely been able to remove all "pause" commands from my tests.

Klendathu